# Changed a value in my development.rb but it did not reflect on nginx server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, amazon-ec2

so i have some json file that grabs the value from config/development.rb

In my development.rb i have this line

```
config.base_root_url = "XXXXXXsome URLXXXXXXX"
```

and in my json.jbuilder file at views i have this line

```
url: Rails.application.config.base_root_url + "views/somesite"
```

How come, when I change the config.base_root_url value it is not reflected on my nginx hosted domain. but on Localhost , it shows my changes ? i tried restarting my nginx server but its still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Is `config/development.rb` a file you added? Or do you mean `config/environments/development.rb`. Your nginx will run the app in production env hence you will need to edit `config/environment/production.rb` as well.

Comment: yes its at  config/environments/development.rb. and funny thing is like... production.rb has a totaly different value , so i don't see how changing that will help.

Comment: Servers run in production env, never in development env.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do changes in `config/environments/production.rb` file to reflect changes in app running by `nginx` because it runs you app in production environment.

Comment: well.. the thing is im actually helping someone on this project , so im not that familiar .and when i check on production.rb , its a totally different value.

Comment: Base root url is different for development and production